AWS Lambda Proxied Internet Access
I have a Python Lambda function that queries my EC2 instance within a private VPC. I also attempted to query an external IP address, but I was disappointed to find out that it requires a NAT setup, which is a bit pricey for a personal project.
I thought of using my EC2 instance in the private network (which already has internet access) as a proxy with Squid for my AWS Lambda function.
Is there a more efficient way to achieve this without incurring the cost of a NAT?
I tried to achieve this before using the AWS NAT, which is expensive.

While not ideal, you could potentially introduce a 2nd Lambda function that is not in your VPC. It will have outbound internet access and can be invoked securely from your original, in-VPC Lambda function.

Cheapest alternative solution is to provision a very small EC2 instance and use that as NAT gateway for your Lambda function.
This can be seemingly easily achieved using fck-nat. There are even complete examples and Terraform modules to provision a configured EC2 instance for usage as NAT gateway:
https://fck-nat.dev/stable/deploying/
